# Struts2, String null check

Tags: jsp, struts2, null-check

I'm trying to do a null check on a String but it won't work.

```
<s:iterator value="matrix" var="row">
    <tr>
       <s:iterator value="value" var="col">
            <td>    
                <s:if test="%{#col==null}">0</s:if>
                <s:else><s:property value="col"/></s:else>
            </td>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

matrix is a

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

The var "col" is correctly assigned a String value from the List.
The list may look like this [ "hello" , null , "world ]

Current output: hello world
Wanted output: hello **0** world

/Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try it without the #.

```
 <s:if test="%{col==null}">0</s:if>
```

I think the has will attempt to resolve 'col' first, and use the value of col as the property name.  Since that'd be empty, it'd do a comparison of "" as the property name, which is the top of the value stack.  I'm not sure how that would evaluate here.

I always use something like this:

```
<s:if test="%{licenseStatusString != null}">
 ... something that uses licenseStatusString
</s:if>
```

Comment: <s:if test="%{col==null}">0</s:if> gives

Output: 0 0 0

Comment: replace 'col' in the if with 'top' and see

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately this gives the same problem with an empty cell instead of null. I think I won't bother anymore with this struts problem and make the change in JAVA i.e. Loop through the array and change null to "0".

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you're using Struts2.0.x or a higher version, as `id` attribute has been [replaced](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html#iterator) for `var` attribute in `s:iterator` since Struts2.1.x.

Asuming Struts 2.1.x, the best way is to assign `var` attribute and use it as a variable (as you already suggested)

```
<s:iterator value="bar" var="foo">
    <s:if test="#foo==null || #foo==''">0</s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

You may also want to use `top` variable to get top stack value, but it may enter in conflict with your objects attributes. Still it works

```
<s:iterator value="bar">
    <s:if test="top==null || top==''">0</s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

But, if you only need to print String's result, with no conditions, whether it is `null` or *empty*, just do it as simple as this

```
<s:iterator value="bar">
    <s:property /> <!-- prints iterator current value or '' if its null -->
</s:iterator>
```

Ps. It's not necessary to use ognl markup **`%{}`** inside the `test` attribute of a `s:if`, or the `value` attribute of a `s:property`.

For more examples check [struts2 iterator doc](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem.

```
<s:if test="%{#col==''}">0 </s:if>
```

The value in the string array wasn't null but an empty String.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line ( single if statement):

```
<s:property value="%{col==null ? '0':col}"/></s:else>
```

Or add more string

```
<s:property value="%{col==null ? '0': 'The column is' + col}"/></s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing it inside iterator in Struts2; inside 'Test Clause', use '#' to refer to the context variable.

```
            <s:iterator value="pageVo.voList" var="vo">
                    <s:if test="%{#vo.iconclass != null}">
                        <i class="${vo.iconclass}"></i>
                    </s:if>
                    <s:if test="%{#vo.label != null}">
                        ${vo.label}
                    </s:if>
                </button>
            </s:iterator>
```